# How to get Default Quantity of child product of Bundle Product in Magento 2

Tags: bundled-product, magento-2.1.3

Today I am working on Bundle Products, Here I am trying to get the `Default Quantity` of child product of **Bundle Product**. But I am unable to get the details. Even though I debugged in product page, I am not getting results.

See My debugging child product of Bundle Product.
[image]

I want to get the `Default Quantity` of **Bundle Child Product** as shown below pic.

[image]

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I achieved this by fallowing method.

```
public function getBundleOptions($product){

       /* $bundleOptions = $this->_options->getProduct();
        return $bundleOptions;*/
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $store_id = 1;
        $options = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Bundle\Model\Option')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->setProductIdFilter($product->getId())
            ->setPositionOrder();
        $options->joinValues($store_id);
        $typeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type');
        $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection($typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product), $product);
        foreach($selections as $selection){
            if($product->getSku() == $selection->getSku()){
                return $selection->getSelectionQty();
            }
        }
        return $selections;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using object manager etc use `typeInstance` from product to **get associated products**. Then loop through pulling **default quantities** of these **child products** like below:

```
$typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$children = $typeInstance->getAssociatedProducts($product);

foreach($children as $child) {
    echo $child->getQty();
}
```